# React Navigation Warning: "jumpToIndex is not a Function"

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I recently updated react-navigation to version 2.18.0 and a section of my code which used to work no longer does. After combing through the documentation, I'm still having trouble reproducing the functionality I had before.

Essentially I wanted all the data that the stats screen needed to be loaded before jumpToIndex is called, so that the StatsScreen Component had access to updated data before render().

This functionality used to work, but now I'm getting an "Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: jumpToIndex is not a function." warning. and jumpToIndex never happened.

In App.js I changed TabNavigator to createBottomTabNavigator, and made the necessary changes for the update.

```
const RootNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeStackNavigator,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
         //Navigation options here
      ),
    }),
  },
  StatsScreen: {
    screen: StatsScreen,
  },
}, {
  lazy: false,
});
```

In StatsScreen.js:

```
export default class StatsScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarOnPress: async (tab, jumpToIndex) => {
      if (!tab.focused) {
        await navigation.state.params.update();
        jumpToIndex(tab.index);
      }
    },
  });

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      update: this._updateStats.bind(this),
    });
  }

  async _updateStats() {
    //logic in this function calls updateData() if needed.
  }

  async _updateData() {
   //Update the data
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // Component JSX ommitted from this example
    );
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on Andrei Pfeiffer's blog: https://itnext.io/handle-tab-changes-in-react-navigation-v2-faeadc2f2ffe

Essentially I changed the navigation options to the following code:

```
 static navigationOptions = () => ({
    async tabBarOnPress({ navigation, defaultHandler }) {
      await navigation.state.params.onTabFocus();
      defaultHandler();
    },
  });
```

onTabFocus() now does the same work that updateStats() used to do.